# Using NPM for SCSS but the script will not watch for changes. It gives me a error

Tags: node.js, npm, sass

I have installed Node v12.10.0, NPM v6.10.3. I have also tried to install the node LTS version as well.

I built my project directory and inside the directory I ran "npm init" and after I ran "npm install --save-dev node-sass". Everything seems good up to this point.

my package.json file looks like this

```
   {
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "scss": "node-sass --watch scss -o css"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0"
  }
}
```

After I go to run " npm run scss" then I receive this.

```
> dashboard@1.0.0 scss /Users/adakaitalker/Documents/school/dev/learning/2-september/4-week/9:13:19/dashboard
> node-sass --watch scss -o css

sh: node-sass: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! dashboard@1.0.0 scss: `node-sass --watch scss -o css`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the dashboard@1.0.0 scss script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/adakaitalker/.npm/_logs/2019-09-13T22_43_56_711Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. I installed homebrew and linked it to node then I used homebrew to uninstall it and reinstall it and it works now.